# ¿Cómo puedo conectarme a una base de datos de Turso desde una aplicación Django?

Tags: base-de-datos, django

Estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos que tengo en Turso desde una aplicación de Django, pensé que con el driver de sqlite que trae Django me iba a funcionar pero, no se conectó.

Comparto el fragmento de código de la configuración de Django:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'django-test',
    'HOST': os.environ.get('TURSO_DB_URL'),
    'AUTH_TOKEN': os.environ.get('TURSO_AUTH_TOKEN')
  }
}
```

La verdad desconozco si realmente eso se pueda realizar en Django ya que, he visto un ejemplo con Flask y SQLAlchemy.